# Firefox 29, XPCOM and wrappedJSObject

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom

We are using a custom Javascript-only add-on for Firefox, which is used in some of our intranet sites. This add-on is supposed to load a specific text file from a user's PC, and then expose specific variables to some of our intranet pages.

The current implementation works from FF3 up to FF28. In FF29, the behavior of wrappedJSObject has changed.

Here's what I got in the add-on's code:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");  

function PrivateClass() {
  this.wrappedJSObject = this;
}

PrivateClass.prototype = {
// Component details
classDescription: "...",
classID:          Components.ID("{...}"),
contractID:       "@foo.bar/PrivateClass;1",
QueryInterface:   XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIClassInfo]),

getInterfaces: function(countRef) {
    var interfaces = [Ci.nsIClassInfo, Ci.nsISupports];
    countRef.value = interfaces.length;
    return interfaces;
},

implementationLanguage: Components.interfaces.nsIProgrammingLanguage.JAVASCRIPT,
flags: Ci.nsIClassInfo.DOM_OBJECT,
getHelperForLanguage: function(count) { return null; },

// We use the default _xpcom_factory

// Categories to register
_xpcom_categories: [{
  category: "JavaScript global property",
  entry: "PrivateClass",          // optional, defaults to the object's classDescription. Needed for FF3.
  value: "@foo.bar/PrivateClass;1",  // optional, defaults to the object's contractID. Needed for FF3.
  service: false
}],

// nsISecurityCheckedComponent permissions
// return "AllAccess"; / return "NoAccess";
canCreateWrapper : function canCreateWrapper(aIID) { return "AllAccess"; },
canCallMethod: function canCallMethod(aIID, methodName) { return "AllAccess"; },
canGetProperty: function canGetProperty(aIID, propertyName) { return "AllAccess"; },  // needed to access wrappedJSObject
canSetProperty: function canSetProperty(aIID, propertyName) { return "NoAccess"; },

getFunctionA : function() { return "This is A"; },
getFunctionB : function() { return "This is B"; },

// New functionality, needed for FF 17+
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPConnect_wrappers#__exposedProps__
__exposedProps__ : { getFunctionA : "r", getFunctionB : "r" }
}
```

And in the client page:

```
if (typeof PrivateClass != "undefined") {
  var obj = PrivateClass.wrappedJSObject;
  var a = obj.getFunctionA()
  var b = obj.getFunctionB();
}
```

However, now FF returns `Error: Attempt to use .wrappedJSObject in untrusted code` in this line:

```
var obj = PrivateClass.wrappedJSObject;
```

I've read about the upcoming changes to wrappedJSObject in FF30 in this blog post:
https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/

...but the recommended solutions won't work for me

Note that the wrappedJSObject solution is in the official Mozilla developer docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Guide/Building_components_in_JavaScript) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Build_an_XPCOM_Component_in_Javascript). It can also be found all around the Internet (e.g. [here](https://alexvincent.us/blog/?p=343)), but apparently it has been somehow broken/changed in FF29, so none of these apply.

I've checked the excellent FF add-on [jsPrintSetup](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/), and it doesn't use wrappedJSObject (although it has a C++ binary component too, which might explain this). I've read through a lot of forum posts regarding this issue with wrappedJSObject, but I can't find anything regarding this particular change to its behavior. Can anyone shed some light as to what needs to be done in order to get this functionality working under FF29+?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I added a check against untrusted content inspecting the guts of an XPCOM component, which it really has no business doing. It should still work just fine from privileged code.

[Also note that nsISecurityCheckedComponent was removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794943), so you shouldn't need that part anymore.

In general, the most future-proof way to expose an API to content is to inject it directly into the content scope with exportFunction.

[Extra info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.exportFunction)